# 4L60E small RPM flash during 2-3 upshift

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, rpm, tahoe, 4l60e

I have 2001 Chevy Tahoe with 4L60E tranny. The car has only about 160k miles as for now. **Last year** I installed TransGo Shift-Kit **4L60E-HD2** - actually only the parts that make the shifts firmer and quicker, no shims for the hard-shifts, no clutch springs. The valve body looked in good shape, only the separator plate was showing a slight wear on check-ball areas but nothing serious. The truck went perfect after.
However during last week I noticed that when the transmission is warmed up after longer drive, there's very short RPM increase during 2-3 upshift. It's about tenths of RPM. The shift speed seems the same like it was in the past. This usually happens when applying a moderate throttle for acceleration.
Could it be valve-body problem?

EDIT: The fluid still looks and smell brand new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the ECM tuned by a reputable tuning shop using the AutoCal device and the strange shifting behavior has disappeared. The ECM & transmission were calibrated, most of the torque management was removed and the transmission shifts much quicker now. Although, the 1-2 shift is a bit hard. I will try to return factory 1-2 accumulator springs as part of the regular transmission maintenance, or perhaps sooner.